# Issue with creating new project for unit testing with NUnit

Tags: .net-core, nunit

Im created on Mac new project to test my web rest api, but I can't make to work initial version of project. Every time I stuck on error:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK. (MSB3971) (Core)
```

The whole project are written in .Net Core 7.0.

I checked  in both projects, and they are the same.
Project reference is also set.
Somebody can help me how to make it work on macOs?
Thanks.

After few changes and reverting - both project currently not starting because of the same error.